# Command to start a process in the background and run silently

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I'm trying to write a command in a bat file to run an installer exe file. The important part is to start and run the installer in **silent mode**. To clarify, I DO NOT want the user to see the installer and click through the wizard. They should just be able to double click the bat file and walk away. I have attempted this command in my bat file:

```
@echo off
REM Next command runs installer in silent mode
start /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn
```

The `–s –v –qn` are supposed to enable the installer to run in the background, but they are not working.

Can anyone help me improve my command in my bat file so that MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe is indeed running in the background, silently, with no UI or wizard of any kind visible to the user??

Please help.

Comment: If you run `MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe -s -v -qn` from the command line by itself (outside of the batch file) does it run unattendedly?  If not, you should verify the switches and/or contact the author of the installer.

Comment: To expand on Mark's comment, there is no way to force an installer to work silently if it does include the code to do this.  Only the vendor can fix this.  However, if all you need is that the install be automatic (rather than that it be invisible to the user) there are tools that can generate the necessary key and button presses to drive the installer.

Comment: If I open up the command prompt and switch the directory to my desktop, where the exe is located, and I type `MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn` the installer indeed runs in the background. If I do EXACTLY the SAME thing, but from a batch file, the UI shows (which is not what I want). Please help.

Comment: Looks like you might have a copy/paste problem.  It appears that what you pasted into your last comment uses em-dashes rather than dashes.  This is very likely what's confusing the installer.  Re-type the command in your batch file (or at least the dashes) and I'm willing to bet the problem goes away.  If that's the case, I'll post this as the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these `START` command options to see if it gives you the effect you want:

- `/B` = Start application without creating a new window
- `/MIN` = Start window minimized

---

Edited:

Try putting the command with its switches inside quotes:

```
start /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the UI still shows (the wizard comes up). Only from the batch file is this command an issue. From the command prompt, it is not.

Comment: Try putting the command and its switches inside quotes - see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can test :

Create a file `RunHide.vbs` and put this line in it :

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

and then run your batch file like this :

```
wscript.exe "RunHide.vbs" "Install.bat"
```

and your batch file will be run without any windows (and maybe your Installer to)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

Here is the correct code:

```
@echo off
REM Next command runs installer in silent mode
start "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe /s /v /qn
```

The change was between `–s –v –qn` and `/s /v /qn` where the former does not work, and the latter does.